# How to use plain ruby instead of YAML

Tags: ruby

With the 1.9 syntax ruby hashes and YAML are pretty close. I was wondering what ways there are of using a ruby file to retrieve some data.

Given that our `config.rb` is something like

`{
  api: "My key",
  name: "name"
}`

#### Option 1

Read and eval the file

`config = eval open('./config.rb').read`

#### Option 2

Require the file and then reference a variable

The config.rb file changes to the following (note `CONFIG`)

`CONFIG = {
  api: "My key",
  name: "name"
}`

And then we can do

```
require './config'

# ...
config = CONFIG
```

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Comment: your question is not clear.

Comment: How about eval (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7730183/337).  Not saying it's a great idea, but it's "another way".

Comment: possible duplicate of [ruby: how to load .rb file in the local context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048093/ruby-how-to-load-rb-file-in-the-local-context)

Comment: There are some similarities, but a lot more things aren't the same. Keep your data as YAML when it's on disk, or use Marshall or JSON, but don't trust trying to parse a `to_s` or `inspect` version of the Ruby object. Also, YAML and JSON are portable so you can read/write the data from other languages. That's important as your system grows.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Bates's configatron is a good example of what I think you are looking for. Check out his code and see how he uses Ruby for configuration over YAML.

https://github.com/markbates/configatron

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do option 2. Option 1 is easily done. But using yaml would be better.